# How to convert ostream into a string

Tags: c++, string, function, iostream, ostream

In a function i'm passing ostream and wants to convert into a string.

```cpp
void func (ostream& stream) {
    /* Needs to convert stream into string */
}
```

Comment: What would you want the string to contain?

Comment: As specified, `func` doesn't return anything, and the only output parameter is the input parameter, and that parameter is not a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void func (ostream& stream) {
    /* Needs to convert stream into string */
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << stream.rdbuf();
    std::string myString = ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Note that all output streams don't have a buffer.